# I want to insert data in database but it it not working .... my code is mentioned

Tags: php

I know that i messed up the code and getting undefined index errors and can't connect to database error also thanks in advance

```html
<?php include("header.php");
            ?>

<?php
 
 
 $target_dir = "admin/";
 $file = $_FILES['image']['name'];
 $path = pathinfo($file);
 $filename = $path['filename'];
 $temp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
 $rand = rand(0000,9999);
 $path_filename_ext = $target_dir.$filename.$rand;
 
  
 if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) {
 
               $name = addslashes ($_POST['name']);
               $phone = addslashes ($_POST['phone']);
       $password = addslashes ($_POST['password']);
               $email = addslashes ($_POST['email']);
       $role = addslashes ($_POST['role']);
       $image = addslashes (move_uploaded_file($temp_name,$path_filename_ext));

            }else {
               $name = $_POST['name'];
               $phone = $_POST['phone'];
       $password = $_POST['password'];
               $email = $_POST['email'];
       $role = $_POST['role'];
       $image =  move_uploaded_file($temp_name,$path_filename_ext);
            }
            
          
            
$sql = "INSERT INTO admin ". "(a_name, a_phone, a_password, a_email, a_role, a_image) ". "VALUES('$name','$phone','$password','$email','$role','$image' NOW())";
               
                        // make project the current db
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('project', $conn);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use project : ' . mysql_error());
}
            $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
            
            if(! $retval ) {
               die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
            }
            
            echo "Entered data successfully\n";
            
            mysql_close($conn);
         
?>

  <section>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">

        <form name="myForm" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTextBox" placeholder="Name" name="name" required/>

                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" required/>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Strength</label>
                <label class="col-sm-6 control-label" id="result" style="padding-top:1%;">
    </label>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="txtEmail" placeholder="Email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" name="email" required/>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>


          </div>





          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-horizontal">



              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Role</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <select class="form-control" name="role">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
  <option value="Vendor">Vendor</option>
  <option value="Subscriber">Subscriber</option>
  
</select> </div>
              </div>


              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputFile" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Image</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10"> <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" name="image">
                  <p class="help-block">Max Size 1 MB .</p>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <input type="submit" name="Sign in" value="Sign in" class="btn btn-default">
              </div>
            </div>

        </form>

        </div>



      </div>
    </div>









  </section>

  <?php include("footer.php");
 ?>
```

I know that i messed up the code and getting undefined index errors and can't connect to database error also thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please include all detailed error messages and your table definition in you question.

Comment: Replace `mysql_` functions with something current as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Put a comma between `'$image' NOW()` to look like: `'$image', NOW()`
Also, your query needs to declare which column to put the `NOW()` value in.

Replace `mysql_` functions with a modern equivalent.
Your query is not secure.

Start reading on how to use php with mysql, because you have much to improve.